# Why I get error when trying to send JSON in get request?

Tags: angular, typescript

I use angular 10 in my project.
I try to send object in get request, so I try to convert to JSON:

```
  getData(dataPlan: Data): Observable<Response<InfoType[]>> {
    return this.client.get<Response<InfoType[]>>(environment.baseUrl + '/ctrl/getDataPlan', {
      params: {
        JSON.stringify(dataPlan)
      }
    });
  }
```

But I get this error:

```
 Type 'Observable<ArrayBuffer>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Response<InfoType[]>>'.
  Property 'results' is missing in type 'ArrayBuffer' but required in type 'Response<InfoType[]>'.ts(2322)
```

Any idea why I get error?

Comment: Please share some sample response that you're getting from the API. Also could you please create a minimal verifiable complete example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) to make it easier to help?

Answer (score 1):

1. You shouldn't be sending data like that, better to use post request.
2. Still if you doing so, You can notice you are passing the type **<Response<InfoType[]>** with .get(), and your **<Response<InfoType[]>** might be your custom type which would be having **results** property as mandatory.
3. But the problem is here, You cannot set the type of response you want from **get** request this way, as for now the get request will be giving you **ArrayBuffer**, but you forcing it to return **<Response<InfoType[]>** of response which you cannot do. Thats why it's showing you the error.

Solution:

1. remove **<Response<InfoType[]>** from
   **return this.client.get<Response<InfoType[]>>(en...** and it should look like **return this.client.get(en...**

Still, if you want to pass the type you can do it where you might be subscribing to this observable.

for ex:

```
getData(dataPlan).subscribe((result:Response<InfoType[])=>
{
// result from request
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well. There is a lot wrong here.

1. You try to send an object in a get request. If you are sending data with your request you should make a post request.
2. `params: {JSON.stringify(dataPlan)}`. That's just invalid JSON.
3. `Response<InfoType[]>` No idea what that refers to. Let's call it `MyType` instead.
4. I am assuming `client` is a `HttpClient`

Now we end up with something like:

```
getData(dataPlan: Data): Observable<MyType> {
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json'
    })
  };
  return this.client.post<MyType>( `${environment.baseUrl}/ctrl/getDataPlan`, dataPlan, httpOptions );
}
```

More about http-requests in the official docs: https://angular.io/guide/http